# New date function is not returning future date as expected

Tags: javascript

I need Date in IST format so here I am trying to pass the date into three formats, first format gives the correct result but I need the second and third format where the year is passed in the last two digits but if the digits are less then 50 it's giving correct result if it is more then 50 it's giving 1950 as year, in my code I need it to pass as two digits only.

Basically, I need the date format as dd-mm-yy or dd/mm/yy

```js
console.log(new Date(
  `04/1/2050`
))// correct
console.log(new Date(
  `04/1/50`
))// false
  console.log(new Date(
    `04/1/40`
  ))// correct
```

Comment: So what is your question? This reads like you expect others to write a parser for you? what have you tried?

Comment: Dates don't have a "format" until you turn them into strings, so: create them with the full year because is "50" 1950, or 2050? Who knows? Well: you do, so tell JS what you want, and then use a date formatter to get the actual string you want, all the way at the point where you _actually_ need a string and not a date object anymore.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
actually, I am getting exponential values like 450, 221 which means, 2 is the month and 21 is year or 4 is the month and 50 is the year which is definitely a future year

Comment: So you need to break those strings up and validate each part before passing to Date constructor

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the answer I tried using moment also it was still getting the same result I broke the data in different formats and tried multiple ways I cant post all those findings here It is a simple question whether is there a format where we can add yy that's it

Comment: i did break all but how do i know 50 is considered as 2050 or 2150? but it cant be 1950 for sure

Comment: I doubt there is without writing it yourself. Moment does let you tell it the format you are passing in but it's not going to be able to guess which century. That would be on you

Comment: Write a converter to convert the input string to what a `Date` constructor actually understand, then pass the converted string to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: "how do i know 50 is considered as 2050 or 2150", if you don't know, no one could ever know. This is your program and its behaviour should be defined by you.

Comment: because 50 is what i am getting from API results i need to pass if i get 450 then i am breaking it and converting it as 04/1/50, 50 should current year number then 449 is working correctly is my question

Comment: Then you just convert it to "4/1/2050" if you know it is 2050. Why stop at 50?

Comment: but i guess this will work const date = moment(`50`, "YY")
      const year = date.format("YYYY")

now i found this

Comment: That will have the same century problems. You need to write the rules for the century and pad the year accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl sorry i dint understand century problems means like how?

Comment: I mean like add the "20" to "50" to get  "2050"

Comment: okay i think there is no such format though I will convert it based on the year

Comment: Right.... no library will do it for you. You have to write the logic and do the conversion yourself. Those values are not of any standardized format that js is aware of

Comment: okay thank  you i will see what I can do for it  @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Following are the rules from ECMA (https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date-constructor)

```
If 0 ≤ yi ≤ 99, let yr be 1900 + yi; otherwise, let yr be y.
```

So this

```
console.log(new Date(
    `04/1/40`
  ))

// 1940-03-31
```

I guess Browser's are taking liberty in this rule. And changed this rule to something like

```
If 0 ≤ yi ≤ 49, let yr be 2000 + yi
```

You can use same logic in your code too. But make sure it is implemented same way in every browser.

Comment: This helps explain the "why" but doesn't solve the problem. It is not an answer